# C# Comparing two sorted lists and outputting to a file

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to compare a list of strings compiled together against a master list and print them out to a text file.  The problem I'm having is the printable list remains empty.  How do I populate the third list?  And, is this a proper use of `List<>`, if not, what should I use?

**Edit**: Sorry about that, prior to this method running, `textInput` and `textCompare` read from two files and are populated with strings 7 characters in length: one pulled from a text file, the other from an excel sheet.  I then remove any nulls, and attempt to compare the two lists with `listA.intersects(listB)`.  MSDN mentioned it need to be enumerated through for the intersects to work, which is why I put it in a foreach.

```
void Compare()
{
    List<string> matches = new List<string>();

    textInput.Sort();
    textCompare.Sort();

    progressBar.Maximum = textInput.Count;

    int increment = 0;

    for (int i = textCompare.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (textCompare[i] == null)
        {
            textCompare.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    foreach (string item in textInput)
    {
        matches = textInput.Intersect(textCompare).ToList();
        increment++;
        progressBar.Value = increment;
    }

    //A break point placed on the foreach reveals matches is empty.
    foreach (object match in matches)
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(match);
    }
    doneLabel.Text = "Done!";
}
```

Comment: What does "compare a list of strings" mean? Compare how?

Comment: Instead of code that doesn't have the semantics that you want (and therefore we can't deduce from it what it is you are trying to do), tell us in English what you are trying to do.

Comment: there's a lot of confusion in your code sample, unless you provide a use case I don't think anyone can give an answer - it doesn't seem the sorting is necessary at all - what are you trying to print? The list of unique items in sorted order maybe?

Comment: I'm trying to compare both of the lists and add any matching strings to the third list, then print them out to a text file.  Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description in your comment this would do it:

```
var textOutput = textCompare.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                            .Intersect(textInput)
                            .OrderBy(s => s);

File.WriteAllLines("outputfile.txt", textOutput);
```

Note that you can remove the `.Where()` condition provided you don't have empty strings in your masterlist "textInput" (very likely there aren't). Also, if order doesn't matter remove the `.OrderBy()`, you end up with this then:

```
var textOutput = textCompare.Intersect(textInput);
File.WriteAllLines("outputfile.txt", textOutput);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you have this in the loop.

```
foreach (string item in textInput)
        {
            matches = textInput.Intersect(textCompare).ToList();
            increment++;
            progressBar.Value = increment;
        }
```

you just need

```
matches = textInput.Intersect(textCompare).ToList();
```

if you try something like

```
List<string> matches = new List<string>();
List<string> textInput = new List<string>(new[] {"a", "b", "c"});
textInput.Sort();
List<string> textCompare = new List<string>(new[] { "b", "c", "d" }); ;
textCompare.Sort();
int increment = 0;
for (int i = textCompare.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (textCompare[i] == null)
    {
        textCompare.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
matches = textInput.Intersect(textCompare).ToList();
```

matches should have `{ "b , "c" }`. so your problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: +1; this loop serves no purpose; `item` isn't used, and it's just overwriting `matches` over and over. Obviously it was for a progress bar of some kind, but not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this:

- are the 2 sort calls even necessary?
- use LINQ extension methods to remove the blank/nulls

```
void Compare()
{
    textCompare.RemoveAll(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));

    List<string> matches= textInput.Intersect(textCompare).ToList();

    matches.ForEach(x=> streamWriter.WriteLine(x));

    doneLabel.Text = "Done!";
}
```