# How to compare two ordered lists with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Checking equality on unordered lists can be done with *Intersect*, but how would you compare ordered lists with LINQ? The expression should return true if both sequences have the same elements in the same order.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Comparing two sorted lists and outputting to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215753/c-comparing-two-sorted-lists-and-outputting-to-a-file)

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876508/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-two-listt-lists-for-equality-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in method to compare collections in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
a.SequenceEqual(b);
```

From the documentation:

> Returns true if the two source
>   sequences are of equal length and
>   their corresponding elements are equal
>   according to the default equality
>   comparer for their type; otherwise,
>   false.

See [MSDN for more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`SequenceEqual()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx):

```
list1.SequenceEqual(list2)
```